# Bash assign variable result of bool function, then check

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to create a function which returns 0 or 1 (i.e. true or false) and takes an argument, then create a variable in another which stores the results of that function. Finally check if that variable is 0 or 1 (true or false)

Here is a sample of what I am attempting

```
#!/bin/bash

_has_string() {
  if [ $1 == "string" ];
    return 0
  else
    return 1
  fi
}

_my_func() {
  var=$(_has_string "string")
  if [ $var == "0" ]; then
    echo "var contains string"
  else
    echo "var does not contain string"
  fi
}

_my_func
```

I have tried a few variations of this and can not seem to find a way to get it to work. All of my variations basically just return the `$var` as nothing. Not a 0. Not null. Literally it is just blank.

Comment: Note: In Bash if comparing strings, you must use double brackets like `[[ $1 == "string" ]];`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You confuse output with the exit code.

```
_my_func() {
  if _has_string 'string'; then
```

You should also quote your variables; and `_has_string` can be simplified:

```
_has_string() {
    [ "$1" = 'string' ]
}
```

Comment: You are correct, I was confusing output with exit codes. Your solution works. As I had mentioned in original post I tried many variations, though I think the missing one that I kept getting wrong was putting square brackets around the `if _has_string 'string'` conditional. Removing the brackets made it worked. This is why I was attempting to store it in a variable. Your approach removes the need for creating an unneeded variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

`$(...)` returns the *output* of the command: the things sent to stdout. You want the *exit code*. After a process (or, in your case, function) exits in a bash script, the special variable `$?` is set to the exit code.

So rather than

```
var=$(_has_string 'string')
...
```

consider

```
_has_string 'string'
var=$?
...
```

Comment: Or even `if _has_string 'string'; then ...`

Answer (score 0):

As others already pointed out, what you need to merely use the function within the `if` statement. Here's something you might not have known:

A function can be treated as a form of [compound command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Compound-Commands). And according to bash manual `[[` is one of the operators that can be used in construction of a compound command. Thus, your function `_has_string()` can be implemented as so:

```
$ _has_string()[[ "$1" = "string" ]]
$ if _has_string "string"; then echo "YES"; fi
YES
```

Of course, this is in no way portable, because of the `[[` operator. But we can make use of `( )` or `{}`. Here's for example how this works in `/bin/dash`:

```
$ _has_string()( [ "$1" = "string" ]; )
$ if _has_string "string"; then echo "YES"; fi
YES
$ if _has_string "nope" ; then echo "YES"; fi                             
$
```

Comment: I wouldn't use the parenthesis in that function definition, they run a subshell which is in no way needed here.